# BaseAdapter is not updating data in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I am trying to fetch `Arraylist<Hashmap<String, String>` through `BaseAdapter`, but `BaseAdapter` only shows the first element in the `ListView`, meaning it's not showing complete `Arraylist` in `ListView.

This is my listview xml Rating_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textColor="#6eb5c4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is Rating_layout.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<include
    android:id="@+id/custom_top"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/action_bar_popup" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@drawable/new_background"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.38"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the method which is I used for setting CustomAdapter

```
 protected void Rating_info() {
    pop_pref = getSharedPreferences("rating_info", MODE_PRIVATE);
    flag = pop_pref.getString("flag", null);
    size = pop_pref.getInt("a",0);


    for (int i = 0; i<=(size-1);i++){

        app_detail.put("provider_name",pop_pref.getString("key"+i, null));
        System.out.println("in for loop "+pop_pref.getString("key"+1, null));
    }
//  provider_name = pop_pref.getString("provider_name", null);
    applist.add(app_detail);

if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")){

        popup_dialog = new Dialog(Home_Screen.this);
        popup_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.rating_layout);
        popup_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        popup_dialog.setCancelable(true);
        //final View view = popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_top);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //  RatingBar rb = (RatingBar)popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.popup_ratingbar);
    //  ImageView close = (ImageView)popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        tv1.setText("Give Rating");
    //  rb.setRating(Float.parseFloat("2.0"));
        ListView lv = (ListView) popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ImageView close = (ImageView)popup_dialog.findViewById(R.id.close);
        Custum_Adapter adapter = new Custum_Adapter(Home_Screen.this, applist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

And This is my CustomAdapter

```
private class Custum_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

     public Custum_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> applist) {
            this.list = applist;
        }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.rating_list, parent, false);
        }
        System.out.println("list size*******"+list.size());


        HashMap<String, String> a = list.get(position);
        System.out.println("Position of hash map----->"+position);
    //  String id = a.get("id");
        String name = a.get("provider_name");
        System.out.println("name--------->"+name);
    //  String c_cost = a.get("cost");
    //  String c_id = a.get("cost_id");
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    //  TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //  TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.costing_id);
    //  TextView tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);
        tv.setText(name);
    //  tv1.setText(id);
    //  tv2.setText(c_id);
    //  tv3.setText(c_cost);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

But it is showing only one item in list though I am sending a list with five items.

Comment: You added only one item in the arraylist. That`s why. Check your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So why it is not showing all five items in listview.

because at every iteration of the for loop you are overriding the value of the only `HashMap` you instantiated and add it to the ArrayList only at the end of the loop. Something like

```
for (int i = 0; i< size ;i++){
    app_detail = new HashMap<>();
    app_detail.put("provider_name",pop_pref.getString("key"+i, null));
    System.out.println("in for loop "+pop_pref.getString("key"+1, null));
    applist.add(app_detail); 
}
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

When you do this, you return the size of the arraylist which is 1 because the arraylist contains only the hashmap.So the adapter thinks you have only one item to display. You should return the size of the hashmap from the arraylist.  Do the same for the all other methods.

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
```

Solution:

```
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.get(0).size();
        }
```